# how can I test an MDX function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssas, mdx

2 part question..

**Part 1**:
so these *WHERE* clauses give me correct data:

```
WHERE { [Time].[Month].&[2011-06-01T00:00:00] }
OR
WHERE { StrToMember("[Time].[Month].&[2011-06-01T00:00:00]") }
```

but this returns nulls:

```
WHERE { StrToMember("[Time].[Month].&[" + Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-") + "01T00:00:00]") }
```

i also tried it with yyyymm format. i am trying to use current month.. etc..

**Part 2 (more important)**:
how can i verify what the format function returns? How can i do this in MDX query analyzer:

```
SELECT 
Format(Now(), "yyyymm")
```

I just need to execute the function w/out selecting from a store.. is there a way to test these functions?

---

UPDATE

figured out Part 1

```
StrToMember("[Time].[Month].&[" + Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM") + "-01T00:00:00]")
```

it was MM vs mm.. this would be easy to catch if i was able to test what the output of that function is..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using a calculated measure:

```
with member xx as Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM")
select xx on 0 from [yourCubeName]
```

Comment: +1 for such a concise answer: I'm guessing the function `StrToMember` is useful when integrating `MDX` into `SSRS` ?

Comment: I imagine : anytime you need to dynamicaly create an MdX identifier to lookup the member.